# How to make texturure scrolling animation in Game Engine?

Tags: animation, game-engine, uv

How to make texturure scrolling animation in Game Engine?

I need that scrolling animation on texture to make things like water stream, smoke. clouds...
You can achieve that on rendering simply animating the "offset" value in the texture properties tab. but that doesn't work in real time, neither in game engine. I already tried some other methods like using the "uv wrap modifier", the "projector modifier", animating the uv using the "animall plugin". and Nothing.
Plus, the texture tile animation in sprites, or movie file methods are not fulfilling my goals because it's choppy and not smooth sufficient to make slower scrolling like Clouds in the sky.
I just need a way to animate scrolling texture in game.
I thought this basic game graphics technique was simpler to achieve. : (

Here is my file, I animated it with the animall plugin, so you can see in real time, just hit the play button.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well I've done something simple similar to what I've seen in your animation, using a mesh for each texture and using logic bricks with motion actuator to rotate the mesh, but you can animate the mesh if you prefer. I hope it is what you are looking for.

**Note:** 
It seems that the minimum value for the motion actuator is > 0.004 to appreciate the movement.

Press <kbd>P</kbd> to see it.

[image]

Comment: Well. It doesn't look good enough. and that way with the clouds in a separate mesh all have to use alpha transparency and it will bring me a lot of problems with z-culling. Nice try. at least you have earned a few  points. Thank you for your attention.
I have searched for long a way to scroll the the texture, sad that I cold not get none of the scripts and tutorials to work, as well for using a movie file as texture.
In this main while I found that the max of tiles you can animate is 100.
I'll try if can get a acceptable flow with this 100 frames.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple to achieve.

in UV editor press <kbd>N</kbd> to show the image panel.

1. Activate the animated checkbox
2. set start to 1.
3. set end up to titles x * y - 1 (x=4, y=4) = 15
4. Set the animation speed as you want it.
5. set the x and y titles count as you want it.

[image]

[Here is a video tutorial](https://youtu.be/xsU44uFKYEA?t=436) that covers the steps in more detail.

### Bonus Tip:

Individual frames can be tiled together into a sprite sheet quickly using imagemagick. See *"[Append an Array of Images](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#append)"*.

Here's what the syntax would look like for a 5x5 (25 tile) sheet:

```
convert \( 0001.png 0002.png 0003.png 0004.png 0005.png +append \) \
        \( 0006.png 0007.png 0008.png 0009.png 0010.png +append \) \
        \( 0011.png 0012.png 0013.png 0014.png 0015.png +append \) \
        \( 0016.png 0017.png 0018.png 0019.png 0020.png +append \) \
        \( 0021.png 0022.png 0023.png 0024.png 0025.png +append \) \
        -background none -append +repage result.png
```

Comment: No, thats tileled sprite animation, I have already explain in question why this method are not fitting in my goal, this way I will have to make a huge tileset with many frames to make a smooth slow scrolling of a cloud.

Comment: Well then this is not basic, and you should be more specific, and show what you have  done so far, how looks your proyect with pictures. I use that for water and i misunderstood you question because i read water so sorry. So if you want clouds, have you use a rotating sphere?

Comment: Maybe this addon its what you looking for [sprite addon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnoZUUn7bdM)

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question with my file, please check It.

Comment: Ok i am looking and working on, maybe i will post in 24 hours.