# Can't get BGE animated texute to work

Tags: texturing, uv, game-engine

I am attempting to animate an explosion in the Blender Game Engine.  The explosion is supposed a plane with an animated texture on it.  I have heard that textures can be animated in BGE by using the Tiles/Animation options, and I seem to recall that I did it once, but for some reason, it won't work. When I enter game mode, the texture just displays a static image.  I am using GLSL shading, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Here is the .blend: [image]

Thank you.

Comment: Related [https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77716/how-to-make-texturure-scrolling-animation-in-game-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77716/how-to-make-texturure-scrolling-animation-in-game-engine)

Answer (score 0):

There's apparently a bug in the current version of Blender (2.78c) which won't allow users to use spritesheets as animated textures.

**Try this method to get around the bug**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIQ0xYTAgt0
(Video not by me)